# Puppeteer and nodejs throws error with Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, puppeteer, node-modules

I created an app and ran it on my localhost which worked perfectly fine.
Then tried to deploy on Heroku, added Puppeteer Heroku and nodejs build pack.

Added the following args to the puppeteer launch function:

```
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
headless: true,
args: ["--no-sandbox"],
});
```

also deployed with:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "First commit"
$ git push heroku main
```

So far so good, no problems during deployment.
But when I open up the application, I just see that:

[image]

and get following errors in the logs:

```
 2022-10-17T18:44:50.357107+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-10-17T18:44:52.117360+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-10-17T18:44:52.117423+00:00 app[web.1]: > fetch-data@1.0.0 start
2022-10-17T18:44:52.117426+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2022-10-17T18:44:52.117429+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-10-17T18:44:52.439078+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on port 41022...
2022-10-17T18:44:52.441949+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:69
2022-10-17T18:44:52.441949+00:00 app[web.1]:                 throw new Error(missingText);
2022-10-17T18:44:52.441949+00:00 app[web.1]:                       ^
2022-10-17T18:44:52.441950+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-10-17T18:44:52.441951+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (1045629).
2022-10-17T18:44:52.441951+00:00 app[web.1]:     at ChromeLauncher.launch (/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:69:23)
2022-10-17T18:44:52.441951+00:00 app[web.1]:     at async start (/app/bot.js:13:19)
```

As I can see he is trying to get to "/app/node_modules/puppeteer-core/.." which would be the wrong I assume?

Anyone who can help me out or prefer something else?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you had committed `node_modules` to the repository

Comment: @KonradLinkowski no, i looked it up and its neither on github nor on heroku

Comment: Are you using any buildpacks to install a browser and relevant Chromedriver?

Comment: Can you post "dependencies" section of your package.json file?